First & second derivative of $g(t)=f(\alpha+t\cos\theta,\beta+t\sin\theta)$ and conditions for minimum
If $f(x,y)$ is a smooth real-valued function, and $g(t)=f(\alpha+t\cos\theta, \beta+t\sin\theta)$ express $g’(t)$ and $g’’(t)$ in terms of partial derivatives of $f$. Then deduce the conditions for $t$ to be a minimum, given it is a stationary point.
I’m struggling to get my head around the first part, even though I know it’s not that complicated. (And as a result I’ve been unable to attempt the second part).

For the chain rule in multiple variables, consider all paths from the input variable to the output, form the product of the partial derivatives along the paths and add them together. In this case, $t$ produces $x$ and $y$, which in turn product the output $z = f(x, y)$. So,
$$
g'(t) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}
+ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t}. 
$$
Since $x = \alpha + t\cos\theta$ and $y = \beta + t\sin\theta$, and using the abbreviated subscript notation for partial derivatives,

 $$ g'(t) = f_x \cos\theta + f_y \sin\theta. $$

Note: this formula assumes that the parameters $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\theta$ do not depend on $t$. Otherwise, the formula becomes more complicated.

For the second part, we assume that $t$ is a critical point, so $g'(0) = 0$, and so we would like to write down the inequality $g''(t) > 0$ explicitly. When calculating the derivative of $g'$, remember that each of $f_x$ and $f_y$ could depend on both $x$ and $y$, and of course don't forget to use the product rule.
If you still not sure about the result, then post a follow-up question, and be sure to show all your work!
